# i18next doesn't detect changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

When I change the language of my application, texts in my function components are translated correctly. But this is not the case for constants that are outside of my component functions or in class utilities

**Configuration** file `i18n.ts`

```
const DETECTION_OPTIONS = {
  order: ["navigator"]
}

i18next
    .use(XHR)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        detection: DETECTION_OPTIONS,
        resources,
        ns: "common",
        defaultNS: "common",
        lng: "fr-FR",
        fallbackLng: "fr-FR",
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    })

export { i18next }


export const getLanguage = () => {
    return (
        i18next.language ||
        (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage.i18nextLng) ||
        "fr-FR"
    )
}
```

**Function Component** `usersAdministration.tsx` :

```
import React from "react"
import {i18next} from "/i18n.ts"

const PERMISSION_OPTIONS = [
  {
    value: [PERMISSION_ADMIN_VALUE, PERMISSION_DEFAULT_VALUE],
    label: i18next.t("users.adminAndOperatorOptionLabel", { ns: "admin" }),
  },
  {
    value: [PERMISSION_USER_API_VALUE],
    label: i18next.t("users.adminAndOperatorOptionLabel", { ns: "admin" }),
  },
]

export const UsersAdministration: React.FC = () => {

const [permissionsFilter, setPermissionsFilter] = React.useState<PermissionOptions>(
    PERMISSION_OPTIONS[0]
)


const { t } = useTranslation()

return(
  <>
    <p>{t("title", { ns: "admin" })}</p> {/* translation ok */}
    <p>{PERMISSION_OPTIONS[0].label}</p> {/* translation ko */}
  </>
)
```

**Function Component** `LanguageSelector.tsx` :

```
import React from "react"
import clsx from "clsx"
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"

export const countries: { [key: string]: string } = {
    fr: "fr-FR",
    en: "en-GB",
}

export const LanguageSelector: React.FC<LanguageSelectorProps> = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

    const defaultCurrentLanguage = getLanguage()
    const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = React.useState<string>(
    defaultCurrentLanguage.substring(0, 2)
)

const changeLanguage = (lng: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng)
}

const availableCountries = Object.keys(countries)

return (
    <div className={clsx("c-language-selector")}>
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="countrySelector" aria-label="Select country">
                <select
                    id="countrySelector"
                    value={currentLanguage}
                    onChange={(event) => changeLanguage(event?.target?.value)}
                >
                    {availableCountries.map((country) => {
                        return (
                            <option key={country} value={country}>
                                {t(`availableTranslatedCountries.${country}`)}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably be because `PERMISSION_OPTIONS` is defined outside of render. The component that uses it *will* rerender because `t` changes and it already uses `useTranslation`, but it won't reevaluate the constant. That's stored their forever as soon as the file loads.

So the constant is defined once and never executed again with the new `t`. That means it only evaluates the constant once and then that same constant is read from (unchanged) when `UsersAdministration` accesses it.

To fix, you need to define those maps in custom hook. You could also inline the constant in render, it would have the same effect. Since the translations are dependent on T and T now changes, it has to be reevaluated as part of the render process, it's unavoidable.

```
const usePermissionsTranslations = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return [{
    value: [PERMISSION_ADMIN_VALUE, PERMISSION_DEFAULT_VALUE],
    label: t("users.adminAndOperatorOptionLabel", { ns: "admin" }),
  },
  {
    value: [PERMISSION_USER_API_VALUE],
    label: t("users.adminAndOperatorOptionLabel", { ns: "admin" }),
  }]
}

// ...

export const UsersAdministration: React.FC = () => {
    const permissionsTranslations = usePermissionsTranslations()

    const [permissionsFilter, setPermissionsFilter] = React.useState<PermissionOptions>(
    permissionsTranslations[0]
)


const { t } = useTranslation()

return(
  <>
    <p>{t("title", { ns: "admin" })}</p>
    <p>{permissionsTranslations[0].label}</p>
  </>
)
```